# WPF ListView selected item visible

Tags: wpf, listview, selecteditem

I have a `ListView` that has its `ItemsSource` on binding with an `ObservableCollection`.

```
 <ListView
     Name="ShapesList"
     ItemsSource="{Binding ChartViewModel.ShapeList}"
     Grid.Row="1"
     Margin="10,0,10,5"
     SelectionMode="Multiple">
     <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                     <GridViewColumn>
                           <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                 <DataTemplate>
                                       <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=DataContext.IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Path=Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}" />
                                   </DataTemplate>
                             </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                       </GridViewColumn>
                       <GridViewColumn Header="PdC" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />      
               </GridView.Columns> 
             </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
```

This window has a model responsible of the logic: it calculates the checked item of the `ListView`. What I need is that when the window is open, the checked item of the `ListView` is visible.

I tried with

```
ShapesList.ScrollIntoView(ChartViewModel.GetIndexOfSelectedROI());
```

but it doesn't work, even if the method returns the correct index.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview(v=vs.110).aspx) `ListView.ScrollInToView` takes the object you want to make visible as its parameter, not the index.

Comment: It's true! 
ShapesList.SelectedIndex = ChartViewModel.GetIndexOfSelectedROI(); ShapesList.ScrollIntoView(ShapesList.SelectedItem); 
solved the problem. Thanks!