# How do you make a Windows.Forms ListView item scroll into view?

Tags: winforms, listview, scroll, visible

I use a `ListView` to show a list of items. When a new item is added, or the user moves one up or down (via buttons), I want the list to scroll to show/keep the item visible to the user. How can I do this?

Most articles I've found point to the `ScrollIntoView()` method or give complex code solutions. E.g. this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793402/wpf-listview-selected-item-visible) uses `ScrollIntoView()` in WPF, but that isn't available for a `ListView` in Windows.Forms.

Comment: ScrollIntoView() is available for a ListBox in Windows.Forms; it's a puzzle why it isn't available for ListView when it is in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ListView.EnsureVisible(index)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.ensurevisible), which takes the index of the item you want to be visible. This will scroll the given item into view.

Another option is to use `ListView.TopItem = itemToShow`, but this will put it at the top of the list every time, whereas `EnsureVisible()` will scroll an item that is below the view up to the bottom position, which gives a clearer visual effect in your situation.